# Conditional annotation - dependent on profile

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am using Spring boot.  I would like to do following thing:

```
@IF profile = prod
@CrossOrigin
```

I would like to profile was declared in `application.properties` and `@CrossOrigin` was declared only in case `prod` enviroment.   How to do it ?

Comment: Only `@Component` or `@Configuration` can be marked with `@Profile` to limit when it is loaded (see here: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html). One option is to have multiple configurations, one for each profile. This way, your prod profile will have `@CrossOrigin` and others wont.

Comment: Can you be more precisely ?

Comment: Assuming you are using `@RestControllers`, I meant that you have two separate controllers (one for prod and another for non-prod profile). The one with prod profile will additionally have `@CrossOrigin` annotation. Based on the active profile, spring will load the correct controller that you need. Not ideal, but may solve your problem.

Comment: I don't see a cause for this assumption

Comment: Well, regardless of what type of controller you are using, the point I am trying to make is that you may need separate components (for each of your profiles) and load the correct controller based on the active profile. Let us know if you find any solution to this problem. Good luck!